# How do I make a case insensitive query with ContentResolver in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

My goal is to get all rows from native db with a specific email address on Android Gingerbread and above.

This query gets only the rows where the case also matches.

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {Contacts._ID}, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + "=?",
            new String[] {email}, null);
```

I've read about WHERE clauses to sql where one use lower('xx') but I can't figure out how to use it. Also I learned to you can make the column not care about case when creating the table, but that ship has sailed.

Comment: maybe replacing `"=?"` with [`" LIKE ?"`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) works.

Comment: is it "Your" content provider (You have access to its src) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try (I suppose that mail is String object):

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {Contacts._ID}, "lower("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + ")=lower('"+ email +"')",
        null, null);
```

or

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {Contacts._ID}, "lower("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + ")=lower('"+ email +"')",
        new String[] {}, null);
```

Answer (score 22):

Also try

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {Contacts._ID}, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + "=? COLLATE NOCASE",
            new String[] {email}, null);
```

**Note that added `COLLATE NOCASE` in the query.**

Comment: This avoids the overhead of the `lower` function; and it can use an index, if the index was also created with `COLLATE NOCASE`.

Comment: COLLATE NOCASE Doesn't work for all locales for example it doesn't work for cyrilic

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = this.db.query("UserTbl", new String[] {"UserId",
                        "Username", "Password" },
                        "Username = ? COLLATE NOCASE AND Password = ? COLLATE NOCASE", new String[] { userNameString,
                                passwordString }, null, null, null);
```

Comment: How is this an useful answer? This is not using a content resolver as in the question, and even the COLLATE NOCASE has already been suggested in the highest-voted answer.