# Contacts UPPERCASE followed by lowercase

Tags: android

I am trying to extract a list of contacts from Android, the list returns correctly. The returned list is sorted in alphabetical order however the upper case letters are first followed by the lower case characters. Example.
ABCDEFGHIJ.....abcdef

The following is the cursor I am using:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, "display_name ASC");
```

Comment: how exactly you need your contact list should be displayed?

Comment: is this perhaps you are trying to achieve? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413427/how-to-use-sql-order-by-statement-to-sort-results-case-insensitive

Comment: @vims-liu yes that is correct, how would I achieve that in Android

Comment: perhaps you could try to change the order by param into this?

Comment: display_name COLLATE NOCASE ASC
please let me know if this helps

Comment: you could also try the solution provided here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566207/how-do-i-make-a-case-insensitive-query-with-contentresolver-in-android
using lower cast

Comment: thanks @vims-liu the 'display_name COLLATE NOCASE ASC' worked boss... add your answer below lets get you some rep points..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use display_name COLLATE NOCASE ASC to order the record case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Use My code

```
 private void getContactList() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null,
            "display_name COLLATE NOCASE ASC");
    if (cursor != null) {
        HashSet<String> mobileNoSet = new HashSet<String>();
        try {
            final int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            final int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

            String name, number;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);
                number = number.replace(" ", "");
                if (!mobileNoSet.contains(number)) {
                    contactList.add(new Contact(name, number));
                    mobileNoSet.add(number);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```